# Spotify Apps on mobile

Tags: html, mobile, spotify

Can Spotify apps (HTML5) for the desktop client also be made available in the mobile clients? I can't find any mention of it in the developer guide, but an article dated Dec 2012 claims this feature will be available Jan 2013. What is the status now?

Ref: [Confirmed: Spotify Apps coming to mobile & web in January](http://venturebeat.com/2012/12/06/spotify-apps-coming-to-mobile-web/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're working on getting the tools right for the platform for public use. We don't have an ETA on when you can expect it to be released.

Comment: Thanks! I would be interested in helping/testing this feature before launch, if possible.